# java.lang.ClassCastException while trying to use org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, classcastexception

I'm trying to build a development environment with Tomcat7 and several related webapp and Java projects.

As suggested (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Virtual_webapp), I have configured the following context:

```
<Context path="/vcaui" docBase="/Users/alexey/EclipseWorkspaces/dooks/application/VCAUI/war" reloadable="true">                    
<Loader loaderClass="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/Users/alexey/EclipseWorkspaces/dooks/application/VCA/bin" />
<JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true" />
</Context>
```

I get the following error, trying to start Tomcat:

```
Aug 04, 2013 1:41:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Loader} Setting property 'virtualClasspath' to '/Users/alexey/EclipseWorkspaces/dooks/application/VCA/bin' did not find a matching property.
Aug 04, 2013 1:41:56 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader startInternal
SEVERE: LifecycleException 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader cannot be cast to  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:583)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Does anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the attribute `loaderClass` with `className`. I've used it in the past and took the example from this [bit from the tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Virtual_webapp)

(copying the example, in case the page disappears in the future)

```
<Context path="/mywebapp" docBase="/Users/theuser/mywebapp/src/main/webapp" >
  <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext" 
             extraResourcePaths="/WEB-INF/classes=/Users/theuser/mywebapp/target/classes" />
  <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
          virtualClasspath="/Users/theuser/mywebapp/target/classes; /Users/theuser/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar" />
  <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true" />
</Context>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Loader** tag can be replaced by **Resources and PreResources**. Details for these tags are [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html)

For Example:

```
<Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
    <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
        base="${catalina.base}/{YOUR_DIRECTORY}"
        internalPath="/"
        webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. Spent hours to went to this solution.

Comment: To be honest, I spent days. And this info helped me. I needed several identical applications working with different properties. All ansvers were about putting path to common.loader, but it was not what the real problem is. So. Thanks, man.

Comment: This is exactly the solution of this issue. Confirmed.